# Starting with the Android source code

Tags: android, android-source

I'd like to start looking into the Android source code. I'd like to start with the easiest place. Which is the easiest place to start with - any application / framework? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple google search would provide you appropriate results

Information on Android Open source website

http://source.android.com

Android Source code

https://android.googlesource.com

Comment: I was asking for a place to start with, not the location of the source code.

Comment: I don't understand your question properly. Source code is provided to you directly and the instructions to configure the repo are also provided on the above link. what else do you require to start with ?

Comment: I think "place" needs to be interpreted as "class" or "package". Given that the OP is going to read the Android source code, what is the easiest-to-understand class or package he could start from?

Comment: @Giulio Piancastelli, exactly.

Comment: ok if you just want to see how the code works you can first go through the basic inbuilt application that android has (like calculator,musicplayer,etc).Search for files starting with platform/packages/apps/ in the source. You can later start looking at different kinds of views created for Android and their related layouts,etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the Resources section of the Android SDK site there are some tutorials that will walk you through some source code. Here is a link to the tutorial on creating a [notepad application](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to start with any application first because that way you will know how it is applied.

Answer (score -1):

Start at the Android | Developer Website: http://developer.android.com/.

Under the "Resources Tab", you'll find useful example applications.

Make sure you installed Eclipse and the [Eclipse Android Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). Than you ca create a new android project (File > New... > Other... > Android Project) in Eclipse and check "Create Project from exisiting Example". The Api Demo Application is great.

You should watch some Videos of Romain Guy, too, he's a coding genius.